# Python, Async, singleton event loop

Tags: python, asynchronous, event-loop

I have a lot of async code and I have the question.

May I have a singleton event loop in the whole project or I should use `get_event_loop()` in every function, method, class? Are there some problems to declare it one time and use it from any place in the project?

For example, I have 3 files app.py, views.py, internal.py

app.py

```
app = FastAPI()
loop = get_event_loop()
```

views.py

```
from app import app, loop

@app.get('/')
async def main(request):
   loop.create_task(<any coroutine>)
   return {'status': 'ok'}
```

internal.py

```
from app import loop

async def any_buisiness_logic():
    loop.create_task(<any coroutine>)
    return "task created"
```

Or I should `get_event_loop()` in every file?

Comment: Can you please provide some usecase, minimal working example

Comment: I've added usecase, check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `asyncio.create_task` instead. Loop needn't be passed around in newer versions of Python.

> The task is executed in the loop returned by get_running_loop(),
>   RuntimeError is raised if there is no running loop in current thread.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task